# How to return the value of a named object in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

What I want to do is extract the value of an object whose name input is a string. The R function get() does what I want in R but not in Shiny. In R this would be

```
> a <- 1
> get("a")
[1] 1
```

In Shiny I get an error.

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           sliderInput("slider", label = h3("Slider Range"), min = 0, 
                       max = 100, value = c(40, 60))
    )
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$range <- renderPrint({ input$slider })

  observe({
    print(get("input$slider"))
  })
})
```

Error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4035
Warning: Error in get: object 'input$slider' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: get
    55: print
    54: observerFunc [C:\Users\statsmart\Desktop/server.R#6]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Instead I want the console to print

```
[1] 40 60
```

Comment: `get("input")[["slider"]]`

Comment: `"input$slider"` isn't an object name. `"input"` is the name of the object and you want to extract element `"slider"` from it.

Comment: try: cat(input$slider) instead of print

Comment: Thanks, @Carl, for the answer and the explanation. That does the trick. Turns out that in my specific case `input[["slider"]]` would have also been sufficient.